# Add a block in page content that use viewreference

Tags: 7, views, theming, entities, nodes

I have a content type that use [viewreference](https://drupal.org/project/viewreference) module to display views on page content.

So every field added with the type "`View reference`" in `manage field` section will display the corresponding view.

I want to insert a new created custom block, between those views(witch are fields in reality).

to be more clear:

> - Field 1 => displays view 1
> - Field 2 => displays view 2
> - **I want my block here**
> - Field 3 => displays view 3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [Block reference](https://drupal.org/project/blockreference) module may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried this before, it causes some problems in my site, but yes this normally what I need.